# Kendo Grid Not Updating after deleting a record

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Unfortunately, when I go to delete an item from the grid but it's not updating properly.

I've tried 3 things and I haven't had any luck:

1.

```js
$("#userListGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read;
$("#userListGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

2. 

```js
$('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read().then(function () {
          $('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
     });
```

3. 

```js
KendoGridRefresh();
```

Here is the code for the function:

```js
function KendoGridRefresh() {
    var grid = $('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.dataSource.read();
}
```

Here is the code for the grid:

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="d-inline">Current Users</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary d-inline mb-2 ml-5" onclick="window.location.href = '/user-maintenance/create-new-user'">Create New User</button>

        <div class="row p-0 table-container striped">
            <div id="userListGrid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="delete-confirm-modal" style="background-color: white"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // Sticky header
    function onDataBound() {
        $("#loader-spinner").hide();

        var wrapper = this.wrapper,
            toolbar = wrapper.find(".k-grid-toolbar"),              // e.g. button to export spreadsheet
            groupingHeader = wrapper.find(".k-grouping-header"),    // interactive tools
            header = wrapper.find(".k-grid-header");                // column headers

        function resizeFixed() {
            var paddingRight = parseInt(toolbar.css("padding-right"));
            toolbar.css("width", wrapper.width() - paddingRight - 3);

            paddingRight = parseInt(groupingHeader.css("padding-right"));
            groupingHeader.css("width", wrapper.width() - paddingRight - 3);

            paddingRight = parseInt(header.css("padding-right"));
            header.css("width", wrapper.width() - paddingRight);
        }

        function scrollFixed() {
            var navbarHeaderHeight = 0;

            if ($(".nav-side-menu").height() <= 100) { // On mobile device or small screen
                navbarHeaderHeight = 0;
            } else { // Full screen
                navbarHeaderHeight = 100;
            }

            var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
                tableOffsetTop = wrapper.offset().top - navbarHeaderHeight;


            if (offset < tableOffsetTop) {
                toolbar.removeClass("fixed-header");
                toolbar.removeAttr("style");

                groupingHeader.removeClass("fixed-header");
                groupingHeader.removeAttr("style");

                header.removeClass("fixed-header");
                header.removeAttr("style");

            } else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop) {

                toolbar.addClass("fixed-header");
                toolbar.css("top", navbarHeaderHeight);

                groupingHeader.addClass("fixed-header");
                groupingHeader.css("top", navbarHeaderHeight + toolbar.outerHeight());

                header.addClass("fixed-header");
                header.css("top", navbarHeaderHeight + toolbar.outerHeight() + groupingHeader.outerHeight());
            }
        }

        resizeFixed();
        $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
        $(window).resize(scrollFixed);

        $(window).scroll(resizeFixed);
        $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);

        $(".content-container").scroll(resizeFixed);
        $(".content-container").scroll(scrollFixed);
    }


    var externalId = "";
    var firstName = "";
    var lastName = "";
    var emailAddress = "";

    var confirmDelete = function (eid, firstN, lastN, emailA) {
        var dialog = $("#delete-confirm-modal");
        externalId = eid;
        firstName = firstN;
        lastName = lastN;
        emailAddress = emailA;

        if (dialog.data("kendoDialog")) {
            dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
        } else {
            dialog.kendoDialog({
                width: "450px",
                title: "Confirm delete",
                closable: true,
                modal: true,
                content: "<p>Confirm that you wish to delete user " + firstName + " " + lastName + "(" + emailAddress + "). Once this is done, it cannot be reversed.</p>",
                actions: [
                    {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        primary: true
                    }, {
                        text: "Confirm",
                        action: function (e) {
                            var url = "/apic/usermaintenance/deleteuser/" + externalId;
                            $.get(url,
                                function (data) {
                                    //$("#userListGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read;
                                    //$("#userListGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();

                                    /*$('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read().then(function () {
                                        $('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
                                    });*/

                                    KendoGridRefresh();
                                    
                                    kendo.alert("User has been deleted");
                                }).fail(function () {
                                    kendo.alert("Unable to delete user. An error has occured. Please try again.");
                                });
                                                                               }
                    }
                ],
                close: onClose
            });
        }
    };

    var deleteUser = function () {

    };

    var onClose = function (e) {
        externalId = "";
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        emailAddress = "";
    };

    function KendoGridRefresh() {
        var grid = $('#userListGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        grid.dataSource.read();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var roles = [{
            id: 1, name: "JB-Admin", key: 1, value: "JB-Admin"
        }, {
            id: 2, name: "M-Admin", key: 2, value: "M-Admin"
        }, {
            id: 3, name: "NM-Admin", key: 3, value: "NM-Admin"
        }, {
            id: 4, name: "Pricing", key: 4, value: "Pricing"
        }, {
            id: 5, name: "Orders", key: 5, value: "Orders"
        }, {
            id: 6, name: "Orders-U", key: 6, value: "Orders-U"
        }, {
            id: 7, name: "Contracts", key: 7, value: "Contracts"
        }, {
            id: 8, name: "Exchange", key: 8, value: "Exchange"
        }, {
            id: 9, name: "Destination", key: 9, value: "Destination"
        }, {
            id: 10, name: "Destination-C", key: 10, value: "Destination-C"
        }, {
            id: 11, name: "Nominations", key: 11, value: "Nominations"
        }, {
            id: 12, name: "Nominations-C", key: 12, value: "Nominations-C"
        }, {
            id: 13, name: "Nominations-U", key: 13, value: "Nominations-U"
        }, {
            id: 14, name: "Store", key: 14, value: "Store"
        }, {
            id: 15, name: "Retail Locator", key: 15, value: "Retail Locator"
        }, {
            id: 16, name: "Lessonly", key: 16, value: "Lessonly"
        }, {
            id: 17, name: "Inspection Form", key: 17, value: "Inspection Form"
        }, {
            id: 18, name: "Products", key: 18, value: "Products"
        }, {
            id: 19, name: "QA/QC", key: 19, value: "QA/QC"
        }, {
            id: 20, name: "Presentations", key: 20, value: "Presentations"
        }, {
            id: 21, name: "About Us", key: 21, value: "About Us"
        }, {
            id: 22, name: "Marketing", key: 22, value: "Marketing"
        }, {
            id: 23, name: "Marketing-C", key: 23, value: "Marketing-C"
        }, {
            id: 24, name: "Marketing-U", key: 24, value: "Marketing-U"
        }, {
            id: 25, name: "Marketing-D", key: 25, value: "Marketing-D"
        }
        ];

        $("#userListGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "/apic/usermaintenance/getmyusers",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                schema: {
                    data: function (response) {
                        return response;
                    },
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            UserId: { type: "string" },
                            ExternalId: { type: "string" },
                            EmailAddress: { type: "string" },
                            FirstName: { type: "string" },
                            LastName: { type: "string" },
                            Display: { type: "string" },
                            Company: { type: "string" },
                            AxAccountNumber: { type: "string" },
                            MemberType: { type: "string" },
                            AccessPricing: { type: "string" },
                            AccessOrders: { type: "string" },
                            AccessContracts: { type: "string" },
                            AccessExchange: { type: "string" },
                            AccessDestination: { type: "string" },
                            AccessNominations: { type: "string" },
                            AccessMarketingCalendar: { type: "string" },
                            AccessStore: { type: "string" },
                            AccessRetailLocator: { type: "string" },
                            AccessLessonly: { type: "string" },
                            AccessInspectionForm: { type: "string" },
                            AccessProductsList: { type: "string" },
                            AccessQaQc: { type: "string" },
                            AccessPresentations: { type: "string" },
                            AccessAboutUs: { type: "string" },
                            FilterString: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 20,
                sort: { field: "AxAccountNumber", dir: "asc" }
            },
            dataBound: onDataBound,
            dataBinding: function (arg) {

            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            toolbar: ["search", "excel"],
            excel: {
                fileName: "UserList.xlsx",
                allPages: true
            },
            refresh: {
                reload: true
            },
            resizable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    template: '<a href="/user-maintenance/edit-user?userId=#= ExternalId #"><div class="edit-icon" title="edit"></div></a>',
                    width: '30px'
                },
                {
                    field: "EmailAddress",
                    title: "Email Address",
                    filterable: {
                        multi: true,
                        search: true
                    }
                }, {
                    template: "#= LastName #, #= FirstName #",
                    title: "Name",
                    field: "Display",
                    filterable: {
                        multi: true,
                        search: true
                    }
                }, {
                    title: "Company",
                    field: "Company",
                    filterable: {
                        multi: true,
                        search: true
                    }
                }, {
                    title: "Account Number",
                    field: "AxAccountNumber",
                    filterable: {
                        multi: true,
                        search: true
                    },
                    width: '90px'
                }, {
                    template: kendo.template($("#user-rights-template").html()),
                    title: "Permissions",
                    field: "FilterString",
                    filterable: {
                        search: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    template: '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="confirmDelete(\'#=ExternalId#\', \'#=FirstName#\', \'#=LastName#\', \'#=EmailAddress#\')" style="padding: .25rem;">X</button>',
                    width: '40px'
                },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="user-rights-template">
    #if(MemberType==='JoeBlowAdmins') {#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>JB-Admin</span>
    #}#
    #if(MemberType==='JoeBlowUsers') {#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>JB-User</span>
    #}#
    #if(MemberType==='MemberAdmin') {#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>M-Admin</span>
    #}#
    #if(MemberType==='MemberUser') {#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>M-User</span>
    #}#
    #if(MemberType==='NonMemberAdmin') {#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>NM-Admin</span>
    #}#
    #if(MemberType==='NonMemberUser') {#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>NM-User</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessPricing==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Pricing</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessOrders==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Orders</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessOrders==='Update'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Orders-U</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessContracts==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Contracts</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessExchange==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Exchange</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessDestination==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Destination</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessDestination==='Create'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Destination-C</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessNominations==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Nominations</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessNominations==='Create'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Nominations-C</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessNominations==='Update'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Nominations-U</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessMarketingCalendar==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Marketing</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessMarketingCalendar==='Create'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Marketing-C</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessMarketingCalendar==='Update'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Marketing-U</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessMarketingCalendar==='Delete'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Marketing-D</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessStore==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Store</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessRetailLocator==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Retail Locator</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessLessonly==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Lessonly</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessInspectionForm==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Inspection Form</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessProductsList==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Products</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessQaQc==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>QA/QC</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessPresentations==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Presentations</span>
    #}#
    #if(AccessAboutUs==='Read'){#
    <span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>About Us</span>
    #}#
</script>
```

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: if you open your browser dev tools and watch the network tab, when you confirm the delete, doe the call to "/apic/usermaintenance/deleteuser/" + externalId  take place? Does it succeed? If so, does the call to repopulate the grid from your api happen after that and is the deleted user data in that response?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to read the entire dataset again if only removing one row
you can call the remove() method of datasource:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/remove
`dataSource.remove(dataItem);`

Agree with comment from G_P - the call is probably failing to your API. Check the console for error messages and/or response from API call.